# the relationship of the counting process and the renewal process?

Tags: stochastic-processes

The textbook wrote like the following:

> A natural generalization is to consider a counting process for which the interarrival times are independent and identically distributed with an arbitrary distribution. Such a counting process is called a renewal process.

I understand from the above sentences that Renewal Process is a subset(specific type) of Counting Process.
[image]

---

However, the textbook wrote the definition like the following:

> **Definition 3.1.1**
>
> The counting process $\{N(t), t\ge0\}$ is called a renewal process.

I understand from the definition 3.1.1 the Counting Process is equal to the Renewal Process.

---

I want to know the relationship of the counting and renewal process.

Which one is subset of the other? Or Equal?

Thank you for reading my question.

Comment: I suppose, since definition 3.1.1 says "THE counting..." that it refers to especifiacally process $N(t)$ (which i conjecture is the process that measures the arrivals)

Comment: Aha, so you mean my picture is correct? (renewal process is a subset of counting process)

Comment: Yes , of course. Forgetting the name "renewal ", this processes have the property of "memory loss" . That is , by independence , once that happened an arrival , you can forget all history and think in time $ t = 0 $ for measure for the next arrival

Comment: @sinbadh Thank you very much

Comment: @sinbadh Most misleading comment. As should be well known, loss of memory holds only for renewal processes whose increments are i.i.d. *and exponentially distributed*.